# Условно-уступительные предложения: сослагательное наклонение vs. индикатив

Tags: синтаксис, сослагательное-наклонение

В одном источнике написано, что в условно-уступительных придаточных предложениях сослагательное наклонение можно заменить на индикатив без изменения смысла:

> *Куда **бы** отец ни **уезжал**, она его находила везде. = Куда отец ни **уезжал**,
>   она его находила везде*. (пример автора источника)

Скажите, пожалуйста, исходя из Вашего чувства языка можно заменить сослагательное наклонение на индикатив в следующих фразах?

> a) Куда бы он ни собирался, клал в сумку наручники. (= Куда он ни собирался, ...)
>
> b) Где бы он ни находился, они его везде отыщут. (= Где он ни
>   находился, ...)
>
> c) Кто бы ни взглянул на нее, сразу влюблялся. (= Кто ни взглянул на
>   нее, ...)

Большое спасибо!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1) В русской грамматике такие предложения называются СПП с придаточными уступительными (относительный подтип с союзными словами). Речь идет о наклонении глаголов в придаточном предложении ― **сослагательном или изъявительном (индикативе)**.

Например: Как он ни старался, дверь не открывалась (это **реальная** ситуация, изъявительное наклонение). Как бы он ни старался, ничего у него не получится (сослагательное наклонение, **ирреальная ситуация**).

2) Союзные слова КТО НИ, ГДЕ НИ, КУДА НИ  и др. могут описывать  **обобщенные или повторяющиеся ситуации**, в этом случае **возможно использование обоих наклонений**, например: **Что бы ни предложили, он отказывается** (сослагательное наклонение). **Что ни предложат, он отказывается** (изъявительное наклонение). Этот пример взят из учебника по грамматике.

Для приведенных примеров, **КАК Я ДУМАЮ**, **возможна замена наклонений** в тех  предложениях, **где есть обобщение**:

Куда бы отец ни уезжал, она его находила везде.  Куда отец ни уезжает, она его находит везде.

Куда бы он ни собирался, клал в сумку наручники. Куда ни собирается, кладет в  сумку наручники.

Кто бы ни взглянул на нее, сразу влюблялся. Кто на нее ни взглянет, сразу влюбляется.

Comment: дорогая Sibylla, большое спасибо за ответ! если я правильно понимаю: Вы заменили аспекты (уезжал - находила / уезжает - находит). мне интересно, можно ли в примерах a, b, c использовать индикатив прошедшее время? Куда бы он ни собирался, ... - Куда он ни собирался, ... и так же в других примерах.

Comment: Куда он ни собирался - эта форма прошедшего времени не применяется, обязательно присутствует частица БЫ, обозначающая сослагательное наклонение. Примеры из Нацкорпуса:  Он всегда был в самой гуще толпы, где ни собирался бы народ. Куда бы он ни уезжал, он писал ей каждый день хоть две строчки. Но вот интересное наблюдение: если глагол СОВЕРШЕННОГО ВИДА то возможны следующие варианты:  А точно, говорят: на вас КТО НИ ВЗГЛЯНУЛ, тут и влюбился". Все было в таком порядке, что из соседей, КТО НИ ВЗГЛЯНЕТ, всяк позавидует.