# Употребить частицу "не" или "ни"?

Tags: орфография, не-или-ни

"Ты и так знаешь как я к этому отношусь, кто бы этим ни (не) занимался".

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Условно-уступительные предложения: сослагательное наклонение vs. индикатив](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/429477/%d0%a3%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%be-%d1%83%d1%81%d1%82%d1%83%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d1%81%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b3%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-vs-%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%b2)

Comment: Окно Поиск по сайту к вашим услугам!

Comment: Подозрительный  ник у аскера. С таким ником - да не знать элементарных правил?! Не стыкуется у меня....

Answer (score 2):

**Ты и так знаешь, как я к этому отношусь, кто бы этим ни занимался.**

Усилительная частица НИ используется в сложноподчиненных предложениях с придаточным уступительным  и в данном случае имеет обобщающее значение.

В сочетании КТО БЫ НИ  используется союзное слово КТО.

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ (что нужно знать о частице НИ)**

1) Частица НИ **является отрицательной только в некоторых конструкциях**, например: ни шагу дальше;  ни с места  (здесь она практически совмещает функции отрицания и усиления).

2) В остальных случаях НИ следует рассматривать как **усилительную** частицу, а именно:

а) при наличии в предложении **отрицательной частицы НЕ**: не встретил ни одного человека;

б) **в уступительных конструкциях с местоимениями** КТО НИ, ГДЕ НИ (в них нет отрицания, но выражено уступительное или обобщающее значение: как ни старался, не мог вспомнить (= хотя очень старался).

Информация соответствует http://www.slovari.ru/default.aspx?p=5310&0a0=20

**Примечание**

1) Повтор слов ***к этому, этим***.

Возможное редактирование: **Ты и так знаешь, как я к таким вещам отношусь, кто бы этим ни занимался.**

2) Запятая ставится перед придаточным предложением (союзное слово КАК).

Answer (score -2):

1. Есть общее правило для отличия "не" от "ни":

> Слово "ни" есть синоним слову "и", будь то частицей или союзом: частица "ни"=частица "и"; союз "ни… ни"=союз "и". Оно лишь дополняет отрицание, а не порождает (так же может себя вести и "и"), либо отрицание вообще не даёт, как в Вашем случае, как и "и".
>
> Слово "не" не есть синоним слову "и". Оно само порождает отрицание.

Так что верно "ни". Сравните:

> Ты и так знаешь, как я к этому отношусь, кто бы этим **ни** занимался.
>
> Ты и так знаешь, как я к этому отношусь, кто бы этим **и** занимался.

Comment: Приведите, пожалуйста, ссылку на общее правило о том, что слово "ни" есть синоним слову "и",

Comment: 1. Я это понял опытным путём и оказался верен.

Comment: Тогда так и говорите, что это ваше личное мнение, а то люди будут искать это общее правило в академических  справочниках по грамматике или правописанию. Достаточно добавить: "я думаю, что есть общее правило...." -  и тогда никаких вопросов.

Comment: *Я это понял опытным путём и оказался верен* - а вы не подумали, могут ли понять вас другие?! Во-первых, вы очень вольно понимаете термин "синоним". Во-вторых, мнение ваше не авторитетно. В-третьих, сложно пользоваться. Ну и главное. Если что-то рациональное в ваших словах и есть, то это все укладывается в куда более понятную и емкую формулировку: НЕ - частица отрицательная, а НИ - усилительная. И на этом строится все "школьное" объяснение.правила.